# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Occur even after CORS enabled on my API ;

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, reactjs, cors

In my react app this will shows. when I try to make a post request. I'm using .net core 2.2 webapi for the backend.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5050/api/Users. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5050/api/Users. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
```

In my .net core webapi. I have enabled the cors as well.
using `IServiceCollection services`

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
    });
```

and `IApplicationBuilder app`

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

also I used this in controller.

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
```

Edit: On debug console output.

```
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5050/api/Users  
    Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5050/api/Users  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
    Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
    Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
    Request finished in 9.3884ms 405 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 9.3884ms 405
```

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS?

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble I think so. I'm using VSCode & .net CLI for this project.

Comment: How are you running the backend? Do you start it using `dotnet run` from the command line, or are you debugging using VSCode? What does your `launchSettings.json` look like?

Comment: @rickvdbosch yes I try both ways. launch.json is auto-generated by vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I should thank all who tried to help me. I have solved the issue.

First I uninstalled the **IIS** using **Add and Remove Programs**.
And I also I have turned off the **IIS** feature from **Windows Features**.

It requires to restart the PC. 
After that, that issue doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check is if this error message is not the result of an error in the web api.

To do this run chrome (windows) in a special mode

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

If you still get the error then I suspect it might be due to some other error in your web api.  Have you checked the api console for any exceptions?

Cheers

Comment: It's working on chrome in that special mode. Do you know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using full IIS and having issues, make sure you rule out:

```
IIS > App or Directory \ HTTP Response Headers \ Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Being set already. I had an issue whereby it was already set for some reason and was overriding the app's config.

Answer (score 0):

Try Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://IPorDomain:Port"); It works in .Net Core Web API. In my case i am consuming the Web api from angular.

```
var itemsOnPage = await _context.Employees
            .OrderBy(e => e.EmpFirstName)               
            .Skip(count * pageIndex)
            .Take(count)
            .ToListAsync();

/*This*/
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
/*This*/
return Ok(itemsOnPage);
```